# Trouble with counters

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++ and have an assignment to edit this code to make it work. For some reason, when I use a combination of multiple positive or negative numbers, it gives the answer that I've entered multiple numbers an extra number.

Example:

I enter 3 postive numbers and 1 negative number.  The counter displays 4 positive and 1 negative.  Same thing happens if I start with negative numbers instead of positive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number   = 0;
    int positive = 0;   //counter
    int negative = 0;   //counter
    int totalPositive = 0;
    int totalNegative = 0;

    //get a number
    cout << "Enter a positive or negative integer (enter 0 to end): ";
    cin >> number;

    while (number != 0)
    {
        //update counters
        if (number > 0)
        {   
            positive =+ 1;
        }   
        else 
            negative =+ 1;

        //end if

        //get another number
        cout << "Enter another positive or negative integer (enter 0 to end): ";
        cin >> number;
        totalPositive += positive;
        totalNegative += negative;
    }//end while

    //display counters
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Total positive numbers: " << totalPositive << endl;
    cout << "Total negative numbers: " << totalNegative << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}   //end of main function
```

Comment: To increment by x write `+= x`, instead of `=+ x`. The latter is equivalent to `= +x`, or just `= x`.

Comment: Why are you using =+ instead of += within the if statement?

Comment: You should accept one of these answers as a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int positive = 0;
    int negative = 0;

   do{

        cout << "Enter a positive or negative integer (enter 0 to end): ";
        cin >> number;

        if (number > 0)
           positive += 1;

        else if(number<0)
           negative += 1;


    }while(number!=0);
    //end while

    //display counters
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Total positive numbers: " << positive << endl;
    cout << "Total negative numbers: " << negative << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}   //end of main function
```

You don't have to use `total positive` and `total negative`, unless you want to have the summation of the positive numbers and the negative ones.

Answer (score 1):

`positive` is accumulating, but `totalPositive` is accumulating your accumulation.  Try `totalPositive++` (and the negative version) in your `if` statement, and eliminate variables `positive` and `negative`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note the `=+` is not an operator (Unlike `+=` which increments the value)

The line

```
positive =+ 1
```

is just interpreted as assigned `+1` to positive (which is what you want) but can be just written as

```
positive = 1
```

This though brings us to the actual point which is that you don't reset positive or negative back to zero each time around the loop.

Once both positive and negative are assigned to `1` (i.e. when you have entered at least one of each), every time both `totalPositive` and `totalNegative` will be incremented.

You may want to consider whether you need the variables positive or negative at all.

Answer (score 1):

The logic error in your program is that `positive` and `negative` never get reset to `0` once they are set to `1`.

If your first two numbers are such that one is a negative number and the other is a positive number, `totalPositive` and `totalNegative` will keep increasing after that regardless of the value of `number`.

You can simplify your logic to:

```
//get a number
cout << "Enter a positive or negative integer (enter 0 to end): ";

while (cin >> number && number != 0)
{
   //update counters
   if (number > 0)
   {   
      ++totalPositive;
   }   
   else 
   {
      ++totalNegative;
   }

   //get another number
   cout << "Enter another positive or negative integer (enter 0 to end): ";
}//end while
```

Answer (score 0):

SOmething that might help is to do this for the while loop instead

```
while (number != 0)
{
positive = 0;
negative = 0;
//update counters
if (number > 0)
{   
    positive = 1;
}   
else 
   negative = 1;

//end if

//get another number
cout << "Enter another positive or negative integer (enter 0 to end): ";
cin >> number;
totalPositive +=positive;
totalNegative +=negative;
}
```

Otherwise you're doing this thing that's basically 1 + 2 + 3 + 4... for every time the loop runs. By setting each value to 0, it ensures that totalPositive only increases once every loop. Otherwise it grows exponentially

Comment: Good, but this does need to reset `positive` and `negative` after use each time through the loop.

Comment: Yes, another thing you could do is completely remove positive and negative and just put "totalpositive++;" in the first is statement and "totalnegative++;" in the second and take out the last two lines of the while loop. This is slightly more concise and it doesn't allocate as much space.

Answer (score 0):

Well your counters are not reset to 0 after your loop finishes.

When you enter your loop the first time, the counters are 0 (positive, negative), but the second time around, the counters are still 1, resulting in a bad counter.

When entering the loop:

```
positive = 0;
negative = 0;

//update counters
```

This code, could be highly refactored to be more efficent, but that's for another question.